Loss function - computed on one data point or on all data points?
I'm trying to read Jerome H. Friedman's lecture on Gradient Boosting Decision Trees. Unfortunately I have very rudimentary understanding of statistics and mathematics and I am confused, so I hope someone here can help.
Friedman talks about loss functions that seem to be evaluated over single data point. In his notation, the training sample is the set $\{ (\vec{x_1},y_1),(\vec{x_2},y_2),...,(\vec{x_N},y_N)\}$. Each $\vec{x_i}$ is set of input values and each $y_i$ is a scalar
that is the corresponding output value (he actually abbreviates this set as $\{y_i,\vec{x_i}\}_1^N$).
Then he defines loss function to be $L(y,F(\vec{x}))$. Specifically, $y$ is not marked a vector, so I assume he speaks about single scalar value. $F(\vec{x})$ too, can be interpreted as scalar because $F(\vec{x})$ represents the output of the model $F$ which we use to approximate the real samples of the dataset. We feed single data point into this model and get scalar output.
So it looks like loss functions, according to Friedman, are computed on each data point individually.
But in most places loss functions are defined as functions of all inputs and outputs. For example Mean Squared Error (MSE) is defined as:
MSE = $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\hat{Y}_i)^2$ Here $\hat{Y_i}$ corresponds to Friedman's $F(\vec{x_i})$.
So clearly, MSE is defined on all inputs and all outputs.
Friedman goes on to declare that fitting a model is the process of computing minimal value for the  $E_{y,\vec{x}}(L(y,F(\vec{x}))$, by manipulating F. This is expectation for the loss function over all possible inputs and outputs.
Specifically: $F^{*}=argmin_{F} E_{y,\vec{x}}(L(y,F(\vec{x}))$
But in reality we optimize for minimal MSE.
Is this something of discrete / continuous interpretation of the same thing? Or am I reading it all wrong?

I think all you’re missing is that an average loss value is an expectation over all of the data that you have, while a single loss value only tells you about that individual point. They're both losses, and they're both loss functions, but each describes different things. It’s the difference between a person getting a certain score on an exam and the average exam score for the whole class. You can measure either one, but they tell you about different things (an individual or the whole class).

I am now absolutely certain that what I wrote is correct.
The probabilistic interpretation treats the loss function as comparing only one prediction. Then we seek the distribution over all possible values of the predictors. We call this A RISK function.  And since we cannot evaluate it at every possible input, we estimate it based on the available observations (training set or test set) by averaging.
Which gives the familiar formulas for most error estimators like MSE.
But what we do if, hypothetically, we have an estimator that cannot be averaged ? Is this at all possible?

The most common losses look like averages of the individual losses for each observation. But there are exotic losses don't quite have that form, such as the nnPU loss in weakly supervised learning. The nnPU loss is a piecewise function and has the sum and difference of several averages.
